# ORA-00936: Missing Expression Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, ora-00936

I'm having trouble identifying where the issue is in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Using Teradata and it's coming back with error "SELECT Failed. ORA-00936: missing expression".

```
SELECT

,CR.CLAIMNUMBER 
,CR.LINENUMBER  
,SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) AS CLM_NBR
,CR.SEQNUMBER   
,MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) AS MAX_SEQ 
,CR.VOLUME  
,CR.VOLUMETYPE  
,CR.RATE    
,CR.RATETYPE    
,CR.ALLOWED     
FROM PRICER.CLMREPRICINGDETAIL CR   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMS CLM ON  CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CR.CLAIMNUMBER    
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMITEMS CLMP ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMP.CLAIMNUMBER AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMP.OWNERID   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMINSURED CLMI ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMI.CLAIMNUMBER AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMI.OWNERID  

WHERE TRADEPARTNERID IN ('NationalNonHouse','NationalHouse')

AND SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) IN ('17304CD2083','17297CA4107')  
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10   
having CR.SEQNUMBER =  MAX_SEQ 
;
```

Comment: How do you get an Oracle error if you are using "Teradata"?

Comment: how about removing the first comma after SELECT

Comment: Your `Having` will fail.

Comment: @dnoeth, it did. It's kind of a long winded explanation as to what I was trying to do there but I'll repost. Thanks dnoeth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the comma after SELECT:

```
SELECT CR.CLAIMNUMBER 
, CR.LINENUMBER  
, SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) AS CLM_NBR
, CR.SEQNUMBER   
, MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) AS MAX_SEQ 
, CR.VOLUME  
, CR.VOLUMETYPE  
, CR.RATE    
, CR.RATETYPE    
, CR.ALLOWED     
FROM PRICER.CLMREPRICINGDETAIL CR   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMS CLM ON  CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CR.CLAIMNUMBER    
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMITEMS CLMP ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMP.CLAIMNUMBER AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMP.OWNERID   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMINSURED CLMI ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMI.CLAIMNUMBER AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMI.OWNERID  

WHERE TRADEPARTNERID IN ('NationalNonHouse','NationalHouse')
AND SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) IN ('17304CD2083','17297CA4107')  
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10   
having CR.SEQNUMBER =  MAX_SEQ;
```

Comment: Sorry. I should've caught that, the original issue was an invalid identifier (MAX_SEQ) isn't being recognized, I must've altered the code and forgot to remove the first comma. I'll post the new error under a different post.